# LoadError - incompatible library version - /Users/user/gems/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, macos-big-sur

When I try to install modules using `pod install` command in directory `ios` of react native project, I get the following error:

```
LoadError - incompatible library version - /Users/user/gems/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
```

How can I fix it so that my command is executed successfully?
To solve this problem I tried to uninstall ffi-1.13.1 and tried to install versions ffi-1.13.0, ffi-1.12 and do the command `pod install` again. The same error was displayed.
Also issues were opened in Github repositories [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10246), [React Native Mapbox](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1115)

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @mjwunderlich https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10246#issuecomment-761719446

Answer (score 9):

Use the below command

```
gem install ffi
```

This fixed the same issue in my system (Big Sur)

Answer (score 1):

The error for me occured after changing/uninstalling my Ruby version.

Try this:

1. Install rvm (if you don't have it) `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`
2. install latest ruby (3.0.0p0) `rvm install ruby@latest` and set it as default `rvm use ruby-3.0.0 --default`
3. A few times install cocoapods `gem install cocoapods`
4. `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

After the setup here, just restart your pc, I somehow got it working after several errors, updating and resources here, I just have to restart my pc and the error stopped.